# Javascript: Repopulate a list of objects with appendChild and for loop

Tags: javascript, appendchild

For reference: https://codepen.io/skypod/pen/veaRvN

```
phraseArray = ["hello", "hi", "bye", "goodbye"];

addPhrase = function() {
  debugger;
  var getBox = document.getElementById('paragraphBox');
  var makeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  getBox.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++ ) {
    getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);
    makeParagraph.innerHTML = phraseArray[i];
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to get my head wrapped around creating objects in javascript.

The code I've used feels like it should clear the div that I'm adding my objects to, then repopulate it with a new set of objects.

In case anyone is wondering, the purpose is to have it react dynamically to having information changed in the array.

Right now, it only ever finishes with one object created (the last paragraph in the array). I'm under the impression that the for loop should be creating a new paragraph element each time and appending it to the last element inside my div. I must be confused by how these functions work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're only creating one element and then trying to re-append it.  You need to be executing `document.createElement('p')` within your loop.

Comment: This must be where I'm confused then. Isn't this:

getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);

inside my for loop the place I'm creating the element?

Comment: Nope. This is just where you are appending it to the `div`. This is the creation statement: `document.createElement('p')`. Notice the word `create`

Comment: Yes, but `makeParagraph` is a variable for `document.createElement('p');` which is inside the for loop. I mean, you're obviously right. I'm not arguing with you. I'm just trying to understand.

Is appending the createElement not actually where the creation happens. Is the construction of the variable where I "create the element"?

Comment: `document.createElement('p')` returns an instance of the created element.  Therefore, the variable `makeParagraph` only refers to that created element.  if you instead set `var makeParagraph = document.createElement;`, you would have created an html element generator variable, but you'd have to call it in the loop as `makeParagraph('p')`, which would be odd.

Comment: @DaleSpiteri I think what's key to understand is that `makeParagraph` is not a "variable for" `document.createElement('p')`.  You're actually setting the `makeParagraph` variable equal to whatever is returned from `document`'s `createElement` method after passing the string `'p'` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a new paragraph element every time. You're appending the same node, and because you're not able to do that in JavaScript, it virtually replaces the node that already exists.

move the creation of the paragraph element into the loop and it should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++ ) {
    var makeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);
    makeParagraph.innerHTML = phraseArray[i];
 }
```

Here's an example:

```js
   let phraseArray = new Array(5).fill("demo");
   let getBox = document.getElementById("paragraph-root");
   
   for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++ ) {
        var makeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
        getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);
        makeParagraph.innerHTML = phraseArray[i];
        }
```

```html
<div id="paragraph-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fixed it:

addPhrase = function() {
  debugger;
  var getBox = document.getElementById('paragraphBox');
  getBox.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++ ) {
     var makeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);
    makeParagraph.innerHTML = phraseArray[i];  
    }
}
```

issue with your code was that makeParagraph was created once and you had same element added 4 times to getBox element, it doesn't creates new element tho its just referencing 1 elemenet several times. when you create makeParagraph in loop its created in your case 4 times and has 4 different locations in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Make these corrections:

1. You need to create `p` elements inside the loop
2. Then you need to set the `textContent` of `p`, using the phraseArray elements.
3. Now, that you have created a new `p` element, and added `textContent` to it, you need to append it to the div using `appendChild`.

```js
var phraseArray = ["hello", "hi", "bye", "goodbye"];

var addPhrase = function() {
  var getBox = document.getElementById('paragraphBox');
  getBox.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++ ) {
     var makeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
     makeParagraph.textContent = phraseArray[i];
      getBox.appendChild(makeParagraph);
    }
}

addPhrase();
```

```html
<div id="paragraphBox"></div>
```